# Show that the initial value problem $\dot x=A(t) x+b(t)$ has a global solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, proof-verification, initial-value-problems

This is the exercise 12 on page 241 of *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher

> Suppose $A\in C(J,\mathcal L(E))$ and $b\in C(J,E)$. Show that the initial value problem $$\dot x=A(t)x+b(t),\quad x(t_0)=x_0$$ has a unique global solution for each $(t_0,x_0)\in J\times E$. (Hints: iterate an integral equation and use Exercise IV.4.1 and $\int_{t_0}^t\int_{t_0}^s\mathrm d r\,\mathrm ds=(t-t_0)^2/2$.)

and the hinted exercise state that if $f:X\to X$ for a metric space $X$ have the property that

$$d(f^{\circ n}(x),f^{\circ n}(y))\le q_n d(x,y),\quad\forall x,y\in X$$

for some $q_n\ge 0$ and the sequence $(q_n)$ is a null sequence then $f$ have a fixed point in $X$. Here the notation $f^{\circ n}:=\underbrace{f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f}_{n\text{ times}}$ means iterated composition.

---

However I've followed other approach but Im not sure about it correctness, so I will be glad if someone check it and says me if it is correct or not. Above $J$ is an interval and (I guess from the context that) $E$ is a real Banach space of unknown dimension.

What I did was: let $f(t,x):=A(t)x+b(t)$, then clearly $f\in C^{0,1}(J\times E,E)$, hence it is locally Lipschitz respect to $x$ (because $\partial_2 f$ is continuous) and, by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, the initial value problem $\dot x=f(t,x)$ with $x(t_0)=x_0$ have a unique local solution for each $(t_0,x_0)\in J\times E$.

From a previous exercise we can deduce that the general solution to this initial value problem have the form
$$
x(t)=e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)\,\mathrm ds}\left(x_0+\int_{t_0}^t e^{-\int_{t_0}^s A(r)\,\mathrm dr}b(s)\,\mathrm ds\right)
$$
what is well-defined for all $t\in\Bbb R$ and all $(t_0,x_0)\in J\times E$. If they would be two distinct global solutions from the unique local solution to an initial value problem then we will had two local solutions for many others initial value problems, what cannot be possible. Hence each global solution must be unique.

---

**Questions:**

1. Its my approach correct or there is something wrong?
2. Can someone explain to me what is supposed that I must do to solve this exercise using the hints?

Comment: I think you are supposed to mime the Picard-L proof.